# How can we find support and confident in apriori for rules?

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am doing item association in transaction data. I am using arules package in R, to build the rules.
I am sharing my sample data with this link https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak1rt2E1f2gFgV9t7hMVAn0P4gd0

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
df = read.csv("trans.csv")
trans = as(split(df[,"Item"], df[,"Billno"]), "transactions")
inspect(trans[1:20])
summary(trans)
rules1 = apriori(trans,parameter = list(support = 0.6, confidence = 0.6, 
target = "rules"))
summary(rules1) ##Output is "Set of 0 rules"
```

I am getting output as,

```
Summary(rules1)
```

> set of 0 rules

I referred https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56034/association-analysis-returns-0-useful-rules this link before posting this. And I also tried random numbers for support and confidence, nothing works.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks Michael, I just shared my sample data in the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issues with finding the right minimum support and minimum confidence value and ending up with 0 frequent itemsets or 0 association rules are quite common. Read [this](http://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html) if you need a refresher what support and confidence exactly mean.

Let's look at your transaction data first:

```
summary(trans)
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
 2531 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
 6632 columns (items) and a density of 0.0005951533 

most frequent items:
AR845311 AR800369 AR828249 AR839869 AR831167  (Other) 
      84       35       31       29       24     9787 

element (itemset/transaction) length distribution:
sizes
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 
 767 509 306 238 160 112 100  52  69  50  31  27  18  12  13  15   9  10   7   5   4 
 23  24  25  27  28  32  34  36  48 
  3   4   2   3   1   1   1   1   1 

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   2.000   3.947   5.000  48.000
```

The first issue to deal with is minimum support. The summary says that your most frequent item (`AR845311`) occurs 84 times in the data set. Your items in general have very low support

```
summary(itemFrequency(trans))

      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
      0.0003951 0.0003951 0.0003951 0.0005952 0.0003951 0.0331900
```

You use a min. support of 0.6, but the most frequent single item has only a support of 0.033! You need to reduce your support. If you want to find itemsets/rules that occur at least 10 times in your data then you could set minimum support to:

```
 10/length(trans)

 [1] 0.003951008
```

The second issue is that your data is very sparse (the summary shows a density of about 0.0006). This means that your transactions are rather short (i.e., contain only few items).

```
table(size(trans))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 
767 509 306 238 160 112 100  52  69  50  31  27  18  12  13  15   9  10   7   5   4 
 23  24  25  27  28  32  34  36  48 
  3   4   2   3   1   1   1   1   1
```

Short transactions means that confidence of rules will be probably low. For your data it turns out that it is very low, so I use 0 first.

```
rules <- apriori(trans, 
+   parameter = list(support = 0.004, confidence = 0, target = "rules"))
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen maxlen
          0    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5   0.004      1     10
 target   ext
  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 10 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[6632 item(s), 2531 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [40 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 done [0.00s].
writing ... [46 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
> summary(rules)
set of 46 rules

rule length distribution (lhs + rhs):sizes
 1  2 
40  6 

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    1.00    1.00    1.13    1.00    2.00 

summary of quality measures:
    support           confidence            lift            count      
 Min.   :0.004346   Min.   :0.004346   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :11.00  
 1st Qu.:0.004741   1st Qu.:0.004840   1st Qu.: 1.000   1st Qu.:12.00  
 Median :0.005531   Median :0.005729   Median : 1.000   Median :14.00  
 Mean   :0.006803   Mean   :0.057301   Mean   : 3.316   Mean   :17.22  
 3rd Qu.:0.007112   3rd Qu.:0.008890   3rd Qu.: 1.000   3rd Qu.:18.00  
 Max.   :0.033188   Max.   :0.705882   Max.   :21.269   Max.   :84.00  

mining info:
  data ntransactions support confidence
 trans          2531   0.004          0
```

The results show that there is at least one rules with a confidence of 0.7. You can run APRIORI again with a higher confidence. Here are the top confidence rules:

```
inspect(head(rules, by = "confidence"))
    lhs           rhs        support     confidence lift     count
[1] {AR835501} => {AR845311} 0.004741209 0.7058824  21.26891 12   
[2] {AR743988} => {AR845311} 0.004346108 0.6470588  19.49650 11   
[3] {AR800369} => {AR845311} 0.007111814 0.5142857  15.49592 18   
[4] {AR845311} => {AR800369} 0.007111814 0.2142857  15.49592 18   
[5] {AR845311} => {AR835501} 0.004741209 0.1428571  21.26891 12   
[6] {AR845311} => {AR743988} 0.004346108 0.1309524  19.49650 11
```

Complete examples on how to use association rule mining can be found [here](https://rawgit.com/mhahsler/Introduction_to_Data_Mining_R_Examples/master/chap5.html).

Hope this helps!